# friend class declaration and member function declaration

Tags: c++

Why friend class need not forward declaration but  member function need?

friend class:

```
class String0{     
friend class String;
private:
    int size = 0;
    string s;
};

class String {      
public:
    string combine(const string &s1);
private:
    int size = 0;
    string s;
};
```

member friend:

```
class String {        
public:
    string combine(const string &s1);  //why need this?
private:
    int size = 0;
    string s;
};

class String0 {
friend string String::combine(const string &);
};

String String::combine(const string &s1){...}
```

Classes and nonmember functions need not have been declared before they are used
in a friend declaration. 
But why member function need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend class/function declaration IS a declaration in itself and forward-declares the class/function. You got that right.

Now if you could forward declare a member function of `class A` as a `friend` in `class B`, that means you are changing the interface of `class A`.

Imagine I did

```
class foo {
public:
    friend void std::vector<int>::fun();
};
```

Am I adding a function to `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: @GMHDBJD If the answer was helpful to you, consider accepting it by clicking on the tick mark in the top left.

Answer (score 1):

Standard gives an example:

> **13.3 Friends** [class.friend] 3/
>
> ```
> class C;
> typedef C Ct;
>
> class X1 {
>   friend C; // OK: class C is a friend
> };
>
> class X2 {    
>   friend Ct;      // OK: class C is a friend
>   friend D;       // error: no type-name D in scope
>   friend class D; // OK: elaborated-type-specifier declares new class
> };
> ```

`friend class D` both forward declares `class D` and a friend relationship with it.